# Does tcpdump guarantee packet integrity?

Tags: tcpdump, packet, integrity

1. In normal use of tcpdump without any parameter, does it guarantee?

   tcpdump -i eth0 -w file.pcap
2. In using tcpdump rotating by time with -G parameter, does it guarantee?

   tcpdump -i eth0 -w file.pcap -G 60

In both case, throughput is apprx 1Gbit

Comment: TCP/IP packets contain a checksum, and the headers of IPV4 packets also have a checksum.

Comment: thank you, but this is guarantee mechanism of TCP not tcpdump, right?